# how to display multipla plots as one plot

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a multiple plots that are as following when I display them:
[image: ![enter image description here]

I wonder if there is a way to make them a unified plot or at least can make the gap between them go away.
I mean I wonder if there is a way to show them like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

where there is no gap between the plots

In other words, I am looking for a way to insert the 8 colors of 8 plots into one plot and show it like the last image

Answer (score 0):

You can control the width of the line plot using the `linewidth=` argument and define the required amount of pixels for plots, however the plots still will overlap/gap while zooming in/out.

Instead use the `fill()` function between the given levels:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="", overlay=false)

upperline = plot(2, color = color.new(color.white, 100))
midline = plot(1, color = color.new(color.white, 100))
lowerline = plot(0, color = color.new(color.white, 100))

fill(upperline, midline, close > open ? color.red : color.white)
fill(midline, lowerline, high > high[1] ? color.red : color.white)
```

[image]